# Can I self-answer a question in order to demonstrate a modern approach?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer, canonical

OK, let's say that there's [an API](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page). And in that API, there is [a function](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer). This function is critical for modern use of that API, so lots of people use it.

However, this function is woefully designed. It is incredibly unintuitive to use. Most tutorials that use this function don't explain it well. This means that [a lot of users come here seeking clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glVertexAttribPointer). Once upon a time, there was even a *tag* for this API function; that's how many questions have been asked about it.

Now, fast-forward to 2012. The makers of the API finally decide to [make a much better set of functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format). These function not only subsume the functionality of the bad one, they are far more intuitive to use. And a great time was had by all, except...

No teaching materials use it (yet?), so the users most mystified by the bad function won't learn of its replacement. And thus, people keep coming here, asking about this question.

Would it be appropriate to ask a self-answered question about alternatives to this function, so that people can know that they exist? Or is this just the wrong venue for such information?

Comment: The rules for a canonical Q&A apply as usual, may be it's worth trying to write one.

Comment: If you can write a good question asking for a better solution that doesn't suffer problems A, B, and C that the old function specifically did, go for it!

Comment: How would people find the new question? Don't you need to edit old answers, or put comments on them, alerting people to the presence of the shiny new functions? What about adding a note to the tag description?

Comment: A question like "how to use function A to do things function B does?" seems pertinent (an on-topic). Better add answers to function B questions pointing to the new solution too.

Comment: This post needs more jQuery.

Comment: self-answer anything you want.  use the "answer" button.

Comment: I'm dizzy from fast-forwarding to 2012. Exactly _who_ is President?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Yes!

This would be a great canonical question.

However, I don't think the focus of the question should be to "promote it as an alternative", so much as "how to use this API correctly, and why should it be preferred over the older API". You have the right idea in the question proper, I just don't like the phrasing of the title.

Comment: Its important to show what the advantages over the old api are, and how you can translate old into new code/calls